# Angular CSS - Move position of text based on condition

Tags: css, angular

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-py9lmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Its a simple Angular app with a basic type of progress bar.

The amount is shown as a percenetage of the bar in red with a black marker and text showing the amount.

The text sits on the left of the black marker.

I'd like to keep the text on one line.

When the amount is greater than 50 I would like the text to be on the right side of the black marker - so from 0-50 the text would be on the left side of the marker and then above 50 it would be on the right side of the black marker

I have added left and right classes to the marker when the text should be on the left or right but I cant work out how to get the text on the correct side of the black marker and keep it in the correct position.

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.bar{
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

.inner-bar{
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}

.marker{
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 40%;
  padding: 20px 0 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
}

/* .marker-left{
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.marker-right{
  border-left: 2px solid black;
} */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would do the trick :

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'left': data <= 50 ? data + '%' : 'auto', 'right': data > 50 ? 100 - data + '%' : 'auto' }"
[ngClass]="data <= 50 ? 'marker-right' : 'marker-left'"
```

We do it in 2 steps:

- Apply conditionally the `left` or `right` property with ternary operators.
- Apply conditionally the "marker" classes (left or right) with a ternary opérator.

You can see the animated demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5v2xw

Do NOT bind functions in your template, it can cause performance issues, you can simply data bind your `data` variable. I rebuilt your small project without them.